# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I am new to android and want to create drag and drop list view in my project.I am following this [link](https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList).

This is my XML layout(activity_main.xml) contain `com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView.`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is my java main activity onCreate method

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

When i run this code i am getting this error.

```
09-27 09:02:09.266 2465-2465/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop, PID: 2465
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop/com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                     at com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                     at com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                     at com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
                                                     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                            ... 24 more
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
09-27 09:02:11.410 2465-2472/com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.984ms
```

Thanks for your rare time

Comment: This library is quite old; it even asks you to import it into Eclipse, which nobody should be using any longer. How are you including this library in your project? I suspect there's a problem with how it's included and the classes are not part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

to this

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: thanks I changed code as you advised but getting same error.I think problem is in library.Does i need to import any library for this listview?

Comment: @abdulrehmanjaved maybe you should post the entire stack trace of the error.

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
         android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                     at com.example.franscc.testlistviewdraganddrop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)

Comment: @abdulrehmanjaved Edit your original post and paste the complete stack trace.

Comment: Karakuri  did you see whole stack trace?